# Trouble understanding graphical solution to linear programing example

Tags: graphing-functions, linear-programming

I'm studying linear programing for Operations Research. I'm at a complete lost in the first example in my textbook.
The problem is about a company that will try to maximize profits by creating 2 new products.

The constraints for it are the following ones:
[Constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvd7e.png)

Where Z is the profit and X1 and X2 are the 2 new product units that are made each week. 3 and 5 correspond to the amount in 1000 dollars that each unit can be sold for. So a unit of product 1 is sold at 3000 dollars and product 2 at 5000.

Next they present the graphical solution step by step. First step they add a couple of lines. I understand why there's a line in 4 in the X1, because X1 can't be greater than 4. However, I don't understand why there's a line in 6 in X2. The constraint for X2 is 2X2 = 12, so why is it being placed at 6? I understand they're multiplying it by 2 at the intersection, but why is this done? It seems to me like they're arbitrarily multiplying 6 by the 2 in the X1, why is this necessary?

Lastly for this image. How is the line 3X1 + 2x2 = 18 supposed to represent 18? How were the intersections calculated? Which values are being used to multiply there?

[Initial graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxgzL.png)

Last image. 3 new lines. Once again I don't see how these lines represent what they're supposed to be representing. How does that lower line means 10? If I take the points which it seems to be touching, 3 at X1 and 2 at X2, then the equation would be 3(3) + 5(2) = 19, not 10, so where's the 10 coming from? I really feel completely lost with these type of problems.

[Final graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Xblv.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: There are graphs involved in this question, I don't see how I can type those

Comment: Of course not, but what about the constraints?

Answer (score 1):

[quote]However, I don't understand why there's a line in 6 in X2. The constraint for X2 is 2X2 = 12, so why is it being placed at 6?[/quote]
Oh, dear.  There may be a serious problem here.  Have you ever taken and "algebra" class? If not you drop this course and not take it until after you have had the chance to learn algebra.  Algebra is heavily used in "Operations Research"!

You do understand that 12/2= 6, don't you?  If 2 times x is   less than 12, x itself must be less than 6.  They are not "arbritrarily" multiplying x by 2, they are doing it because that is what "$2x_2$" means- multiply %x_2$ by 2!

The (x1, x2) points satisfying "$x_1\ge 0$", "$x_2\ge 0$", "$x_1\le 4$", and "$x_2\le 6$" (which is the same as "$2x_2\le 12$") lie inside the rectangle formed by those four lines.

[quote]How is the line 3X1 + 2x2 = 18 supposed to represent 18?[/quote]
I don't know what you mean by "represent 18"! First, do you understand that when we say something like "$3x_1+ 3x_2= 18$" corresponds to a given line in a coordinate system, every $(x_1, x_2)$ point satisfies that equation.  You should also know, from basic geometry, that "a line is determined by two points".   Two draw a straight line, we can just mark two points and draw the line through them.  Because "0" is an easy number, I like to take $x_1=  0$, put it into the equation $3x_1+ 2x_2= 3(0)+ 2x_2= 2x_2= 18$ so, dividing both sides by 2,$x_2= 9$.  Similarly if we take $x_2= 0$ we have $3x_1+ 2x_2= 3x_1+ 2(0)= 3x_1= 18$ so $x_1= 6$.   Another point on the line is (6, 0).  Draw the line through (0, 9) and (6, 0).

[quote]How were the intersections calculated?[/quote]
We already know that the intesections of $3x_1+ 2x_2= 18$  with x= 0 and y= 0 are (0, 9) and (6, 0).
At the intersection of $3x_1+ 2x_2= 18$ and $x_1= 4$ the same values of "$x_1$" and "$x_2$" must satisfy both equations.  The second equation **tells** us that $x_1= 4$ so the first equation is $3(4)+ 2x_2= 12+ 2x_2= 18$.  $2x_2= 18- 12= 6$ so $x_2= 3$.  Those two lines intersect at (4, 3).

And $3x_1+ 2x_2= 18$ and $x_2= 6$ intersect where $x_2= 6$ and $3x_1+ 2(6)= 3x_1+ 12= 18$.  $3x_1= 18- 12= 6$ so $x_1= 6/3= 2$.  Those two lines intersect at (2,6).

Comment: I just don't get how the lines in question make sense. Look at the Z = 10 = 3(X1) + 5(X2) line in the "initial graph" (which should actually be the final graph, I got them mixed up)
That line is connected to the points 3 in X1 and 2 in X2. That means that the equation would be 3(3) + 5(2), but that results in 19, not 10, so why are they saying it's equal to 10? You mention that if a line is drawn, everything under it should satisfy the conditions of the equation, but I see several cases where in that line where its = 10 there's several combinations which result in greater than 10

Comment: To add more to my point (because I really feel if I understand this then I'll be able to understand most of it). Look at the line for 3(x1) + 2(x2) = 18. The points are set at 3(6) + 2(9), but that's obviously 32, not 18, so why is it saying it's 18? On the horizontal line they're setting at 6 because the constraint there was 2(x) so 2(6) = 12, but here it doesn't seem to be following that logic at all since the result is 32

Comment: 3(6)+ 2(9) is 'obviously

Comment: I think your reply was incomplete

Comment: This board has a five minute limit on edits and I just can't type that fast!  I was going to say that 3(6)+ 2(9)= 18+ 18= 36, not 32!

Comment: You seem to be completely misunderstanding just about everything!  No one is saying that $x_1= 6$, $x_2= 9$ satisfy $3x_1+ 2x_2= 18$.  What is being said is that $x_1= 6$, $x_2= 0$  satisfies $3(6)+ 2(0)= 18$ and that $x_1= 0$, $x_2= 9$ satisfies $3(0)+ 2(9)= 18$.

Comment: Thank you! I actually understood this time around. So the borders of the line are not actually the points for the equation but coordinates where it is equal to whatever value is supposed to be.

(Also sorry about the 32 when it was 36, made the math in my head and I guess im just bad at it)